# Angular with webAPI

Tags: c#, angular

I developed a small Angular app with WebApi, it works fine, and then here I’m turning my app around and showing it to someone, and this one doesn’t work anymore when I haven’t touched anything.

Here is the error in question:

[image: ERROR]

There is my index.schtml :

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>TestExamenAngular</title>
    <base href="/">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
          rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,700" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
    <app-root></app-root>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/angular/runtime.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/angular/polyfills.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/angular/styles.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/angular/vendor.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/angular/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

There is my global.asax :

```
namespace examenASPGENICQFlorian
{
    public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            RegisterRoute(RouteTable.Routes);
        }

        private static void RegisterRoute(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.MapRoute("catchAll", "{*catchAll}", new { controller = "Index", action = "Index" });
        }
    }
```

}

Thank in advance ;)

Comment: Change controller = "Index" to controller = "Home"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Routing has problem

```
routes.MapRoute("catchAll", "{*catchAll}", new { controller = "Index", action = "Index" })
```

Change it to

```
routes.MapRoute("catchAll", "{*catchAll}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" })
```

PS: I believe that you are using default template so  your main controller is most probably `HomeController` thus I changed `controller = "Home"`